# How to count specific combinations in a binary set? (Or all path in a square above some treshold)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binary

I am trying to count the number of possible combinations for a set of bits of length $n$ with some specific rules:

First bit is a $0$, last bit is a $1$. Mix of $0$ and $1$ in between.

Starting from a random combination and ending with all $1$ aligned to the left, I want to know how many possible way there is to shift $1$'s onto $0$'s on it's left (Any $0$ before the next $1$)

e.g

**01101** (initial random set)

**01110** (last bit shifted to the left)

**10101** (second bit shifted to the left)

**10110** (second bit and last bit shifted to the left)

**11001** (bit 2,3 shifted to the left)

**11010** (bit 2,3 and 5 shifted to the left)

**11100** (bit 2,3 shifted to the left, bit 5 shifted twice)

I tried a lot of thing without success.
Any hint appreciated

Thx

Edit:

It would be like finding all path from $A$ to $B$ that are on or above the red line in a square starting down from the upper left corner and reaching the right side (square which side is the number of $1$ and distance from B to top is the number of $0$). A $0$ would be a step down, and a $1$ a step to the right.

initial red path: **0101101101**

[image: From A to B]

another exemple:

**011011**

**011101**

**011110**

**101011**

**101101**

**101110**

**110011**

**110101**

**110110**

**111001**

**111010**

**111100**

Note: I said random but if there is no general technique, I am still interested in the case where there are no more than 2 consecutive "$1$" and no more than 1 consecutive "$0$" which would fit the above square.

Comment: Are you asking how many bitstrings there are overall who begin with a $0$ and end with a $1$?  There are $2^{n-2}$.  Or are you asking, given a *specific* bit string fitting that pattern, how many "shifts" there are where a "shift" is another arrangement arrived at from the original via a number of bitswaps of $0$'s on the left and $1$'s on the right?

Comment: If it were this other question, then *clearly* the answer would depend on the original arrangement.  `0101` for instance is a shift of `0011` so `0011` would clearly have every shift of `0101` in addition to `0101` itself and hence more shifts overall.

Comment: So, 1s can only move left and 0s can only move right. 

In your example, you have $\{0\cdot 2, 1\cdot 3\}$ where 2 and 3 are the multiplicites of 0 and 1 respectively. For this example (and this example only), the only configuration that will not work is if the last two bits are both 1 (as that implies a 0 moved to the left). There are $$\dfrac{5!}{2!3!} = 10$$ possible arrangements, and $$\dfrac{3!}{1!2!}=3$$ arrangements where the last two bits are 1. This leaves $10-3=7$ arrangements where the bits shifted in the correct directions (or did not shift at all).

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes, it is dependent of the original arrangement

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, thx...it indeed works (only) for that case.

Comment: @user489810 the method I proposed can be extended algorithmically where you can count groups of paths. For instance, in your second example, there are $$\dfrac{6!}{2!4!} = 15$$ total possible bit strings with two 0s and four 1s. Any bit string that ends with three 1s will be invalid, so there are $$\dfrac{3!}{1!2!} = 3$$ invalid bit strings. This leaves $15-3 = 12$ valid ones.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe,Indeed... sorry, I tried on this exemple: 01101101 and found 53 with the factorials instead of 30. I'll check again, I might have missed some paths.

Comment: Invalid arrangements: Any arrangement with less than two zeros in the last five positions plus any arrangement with two or more zeros in the last five positions but ending in 11. Total bit strings with three 0s and five 1s: $\dfrac{8!}{3!5!} = 56$. Only one bit string with no zeros in the last five digits. $\dfrac{3!}{1!2!}\cdot \dfrac{5!}{4!1!} = 15$ bit strings with only one zero in the last five digits. For two or more zeros in last 5 digits plus 11 at the end: $\dfrac{3!}{1!2!}\cdot \dfrac{3!}{2!1!}+\dfrac{3!}{0!3!}\cdot \dfrac{3!}{3!0!} = 10$. This leaves $56-1-15-10=30$ valid strings.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, thanks. Is this generalisable?

Comment: Yes, it is called Inclusion/Exclusion

Comment: Another way to do it is to use summations. $$\sum_{a_1=0}^1\sum_{a_2=0}^{2+a_1}\sum_{a_3=0}^{2+a_2} 1 = 30$$ What this represents is that the rightmost zero can move zero or one place to the right. The next rightmost zero can move between 0 and 2+the number of spaces the rightmost zero moved to the right. The leftmost zero can move to the right between 0 and 2+the number of spaces the middle zero moves. (The 2s in that formula are the number of bits that are 1 in between the 0s)

Comment: Nice !!! I can accept this as an answer :)

Comment: To generalize that, suppose there are three 0s in the string: $$0 \underbrace{1\cdot 1}_{k_3\text{ 1s}}0\underbrace{1\cdot 1}_{k_2\text{ 1s}}0\underbrace{1\cdot 1}_{k_1\text{ 1s}}$$ Then the summation would be: $$\sum_{a_0=0}^{k_1}\sum_{a_2=0}^{k_2+a_1}\sum_{a_3=0}^{k_3+a_2}1 = \dfrac{(k_1+1)(3k_3(2k_2+k_1+2)+3k_2^2+3k_2(k_1+3)+k_1^2+5k_1+6}{6}$$ So, in your last case, you had $k_1=1, k_2=2, k_3=2$ and $$\dfrac{(2)(6(7)+3(2)^2+3(2)(4)+1+5+6}{6} = 30$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use summations. Suppose you have three zeros with 1s between:

$$0\underbrace{111\cdot 111}_{k_3\text{ 1s}} 0 \underbrace{111\cdot 111}_{k_2\text{ 1s}} 0 \underbrace{111\cdot 111}_{k_1\text{ 1s}}$$

Then, the number of valid bit strings is:

$$\sum_{a_1=0}^{k_1} \sum_{a_2=0}^{k_2+a_1}\sum_{a_3=0}^{k_3+a_2} 1$$